# RemoveEventListener is not working in Angular2 using typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using three.js in Angular2. The code is simple, as following.

```
this.webGLRenderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', ()=>this.onMouseDown(<MouseEvent>event), false);

this.webGLRenderer.domElement.removeEventListener('mousedown', ()=>this.onMouseDown(<MouseEvent>event), false);
```

I also tried this

```
this.webGLRenderer.domElement.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown, false);
```

I still got the event on the domelement anyway. It seems like, addEventListener is working properly, but can not remove it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How to take this question back? After read this typescript doc https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html. I understand start with ()=> actually like an anonymous function. So when I define the method.    protected onMouseMove = (event: MouseEvent): void => {//do something}   and add event    this.webGlRenderer.domelement.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove, false).   then remove    this.webGlRenderer.domelement.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove, false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use removeEventListerner, the functions callbacks can not be anonymous, so your second example should work, as long as you are also using this.onMouseDown when adding the listener.

> To remove event handlers, the function specified with the
>   addEventListener() method must be an external function.

from [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp)

try:

```
this.webGLRenderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown, false);
this.webGLRenderer.domElement.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown, false);
```

Comment: Oh, I just read your comment under the question and it seems you got the answer already...

Comment: Thank you for kindly answer this question. I'm new to typescript, I guess I should read more doc. Your answer is correct, I will take it. Thanks again!